# The low dimensional end of the brane scan

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, branes

Common wisdom says that only the top dimensional part of the [brane scan](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/brane%20scan) of [Green-Schwarz super p-brane sigma models](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Green-Schwarz+action+functional) is quantum consistent (the critical strings and the M-branes). But by the results in

- Luca Mezincescu, Paul Townsend, *Anyons from Strings*, Phys.Rev.Lett.105:191601,2010 ([arXiv:1008.2334](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2334))
- Luca Mezincescu, Paul Townsend, *Quantum 3D Superstrings*, PhysRevD.84.106006 ([arXiv:1106.1374](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1374))
- Luca Mezincescu, Alasdair J. Routh, Paul Townsend, *Equivalence of 3D Spinning String and Superstring* ([arXiv:1305.5049](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.5049))

the Green-Schwarz superstring [down in target space dimension 2+1](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super%201-brane%20in%203d) is at least more quantum consistent than is typically advertized.

Is there anything analogous to these results to be said about the light-cone quantization of the [supermembrane in target space dimension 3+1](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super+2-brane+in+4d)  ?

Comment: as far as I know, unlike the superstring, there is no successful quantization of the super membrane.